# JOIN TABLES with multiple columns using Query in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to join tables but couldn't really understand what is on the websites. Could you help me?

I have the tables

**Products**

```
ID / product_name / product_description / product_code /
```

**Users**

```
ID / username / username_id / password /
```

**Checkedout**

```
ID /product_name /product_des /username /username_id /checkedout_date / return_date /
```

How can I join from `Products` (product_name / product_description ) and from `Users` (username / username_id) to `Checkedout`?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269809/mysql-join-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining tables is fairly simple. I'll leave it to you to continue your learning, but here is how you join those tables, so that you have a reference to better understand what you're learning.

The idea is that you just have to list your tables (in this case, I've added arbitrary aliases to each table - `c`, `p`, and `u`), and specify whether you want an `inner` or `outer` join, and then specify which columns to `join on`. You join on columns that have the same value in both tables. For example, Checkedout has a username_id and the Users table has an ID. You can use all the same logic you would use in a WHERE clause when specifying what to join on (including AND and OR)

```
select
    *
from
    Checkedout c
    inner join Products p
        on (c.product_name = p.product_name and c.product_des = p.product_description)
    inner join Users u
        on (c.username_id = u.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to update your database schema so that the tables are normalized. Suggested schema for `Checkedout`:

> Checkedout - id, product_id, user_id, checkedout_date, return_date

Now you can write a join query very easily(something like this):

> select u.username, p.product_name, co.checkedout_date from Checkedout as co join Users u on u.id = co.user_id join Products p on p.id = co.product_id where u.id = 1;