# How to connect 3 tables in the database?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

The problem is that i have 3 database tables

- 1st table of users with user_id
- 2nd table is attribute with attribute_id and attribute_name
- And 3rd one is Rating table having user_id and attribute_id

i want to get attribute_name from 2nd table using attribute_id after click on the specific user? Is it possible? If answer is Yes then please give me a suggestion how yo do this? thanks sir in advance?

- Here i'm upload the image that after i click on specific user for edit display its record from user table and attribute_id from attribute table using many to many relation and problem is that we get attribute_name of specific id from Rating table using the attribute_id?? Is It Possible?

Its Edit form and below submit button get id from attribute table but we want to display attribute_name from rating table

[image: Its Edit form and below submit button get id from attribute table but we want to display attribute_name from rating table]

Comment: pls look in another questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269809/mysql-join-query

Comment: Can you post the models and the blade code?

Comment: User Model : 
    public function Rating(){
        return $this->hasMany(Rating::class);
    }                                                                                                     
 Rating Model: public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

Comment: @DanishButt Please update your original question with the code. Also, fix your spelling mistakes and editing as your question is not very readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query::

```
$records = DB::table('attributes')->join('ratings','attributes.id','=','ratings.attribute_id')->where('user_id',$id)->get();
return view('employee.edit',compact('records'));
```

Your EDIT VIEW PAGE

```
@foreach($records as $record)
<h4>Attributes ==>{{$record->attribute}}</h4>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Users model:

```
public function rating()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Rating::class);
}
```

Rating model:

```
public function attribute()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class, 'attribute_id');
}
```

Then call it in controller:

```
dd(Users::with('rating.attribute')->where('user_id', 1));
```