# how to delete n rows in spring data rest

Tags: spring-data-rest

i'm trying to delete n rows from database and n is variable should be given in the api method like deleting the last 10 boxes of items in supermarket which means they are sold so how i would do so i'm using spring data rest i don't know how to write the query in the repository and how i would get the variable n and use it in the sql query also i should check if that number of rows exist before deleting

Comment: Hi @Takla Gerguis, can you share an example, with tables, in order to understand, is the domain if you have also a piece of code that you are intending it could be great

Comment: an example of asking questions of tables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269809/mysql-join-query

Comment: i have table named items and each item has type i want to delete the first n items with certain type. this is a spring data project n will be given by the user i don't know how to get the variable n from the user and use it in the query in spring data rest